# Using NSPersistentDocument to create 'Documents'

Tags: macos, core-data, nspersistentdocument

I would like to create an app that uses

- Swift
- CoreData
- 'Documents' which work in the standard macOS fashion [custom extension, a single 'file'/filewrapper containing all data relating to that document]

This does not appear possible. The documentation states very clearly that

> NSPersistentDocument does not support some document behaviors:
>   File wrappers. [..]

which makes me think that the usual ways of dealing with images in CoreData - *binary data with 'allow external storage*' and *save them to a different location, store the URL in the database*  - cannot be used with NSPersistentDocument. I want my users to be able to do the usual Finder operations on my 'file' (duplicate, move to external storage, restore from external backup) and need all my data to be in one single package.

The SQL version of the file store results in the usual three-fold stack when saving - .sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal - which is useless as a 'document'.

Is there a solution I have overlooked? (examples are very sparse; the [Big Nerd Ranch sample](https://github.com/bignerdranch/cocoa-programming-for-osx-5e) does not solve this, either; neither Marcus Zarra nor Objc.io touch on NSPersistentDocument).

Answer (score 4):

The only option that will work with `NSPersistentDocument` the way you want it is to store the images directly in the database. You need a Binary Data attribute on your entity, but you cannot turn on the `Allows External Storage` option.

If you turn on this option, Core Data will decide - depending on the size - whether to store the image directly in the database or in a hidden folder inside the folder where your document is located:

[image: Hidden Folder]

(I made the folder visible entering `cmd-shift-.` in the Finder). The sample document is named `Test 1.doof` and it contains three images:

[image: Document Window]

You can see that the hidden folder `.Test 1_SUPPORT/EXTERNAL DATA` contains two files, which are the two bigger images (1.3 MB and 494 KB). The third one with only 50 KB is stored inside `Test 1.doof`. If you move `Test 1.doof` into another folder, the hidden folder is left behind. Opening the file in that other folder leads to two missing images.

Storing the images inside the database is not that bad if you put the binary data into a separate entity with a one-to-one relation to the rest of the data, like so:

[image: Data Model]

That way the image does not interfere with any search or sort operation. `NSPersistentDocument` gives you a lot of cool functionality for free, so you should use it anyway if possible.

Two additional remarks:

- If you turn on `Allows External Storage` for an attribute, you do not have to care about URLs or where to store the images, Core Data does that for you (but not in a useful way for document-based apps).
- These `shm` or `wal` files are temporary files that appear "sometimes", for databases without external storage as well. If they stick, you can safely remove them when you app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put more then just a database in your document, then you should implement `NSDocument` instead of `NSPersistentDocument`. In that case you don't get built-in support for CoreData, but you can use your document as a container for multiple file types.

See also [Is NSDocument and CoreData a possible combination, or is NSPersistentDocument the only way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721392/is-nsdocument-and-coredata-a-possible-combination-or-is-nspersistentdocument-th)

Comment: How do I create individual CoreData stores (sql) inside a filewrapper? The linked example proposes a single CoreData store for all information, with individual documents using a different type of storage (plist etc) - whereas I really am looking for a 'document' that uses CoreData.

Comment: You can also instantiate a Core Data stack within the scope of a NSDocument, and save your SQLite, XML or binary files within the document.

Comment: What if the document containing the SQLite file is moved to a different dir while open, will that break Core Data? Do we need to detect the document is moved, teardown the Core Data stack and recreate it?

Comment: @malhal In most cases macOS keeps automatically track of files that are moved while being opened in an app.

Comment: I gave it a try and when launching app then renaming a folder containing the SQLite files when attempting to save the context it exceptions with CoreData: error: Error opening store: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" so my guess is we would need to detect the document being moved and recreate the core data stack at its new location making this thread safe is probably a nightmare.

Comment: I figured out that `NSPersistentDocument` detects file moves by overriding `setFileURL` and calling `setURL:forPersistentStore:` so context saves keep working.